# .htaccess URL rewrite to upper-case characters in domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

For example, I'd like to have **foobar.com** show **FooBar.com**

This *almost* works, but ends up forcing a redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foobar.com\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://FooBar.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there any way to do this? I know it's weird, but I'm just curious if it's possible to do without ending up in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is impossible because a domain name can't contain uppercase, but just numbers, lowercases and hyphens.

Consequently, when you redirect your domain name with lowercases to your domain name with uppercases, your browser will do the opposite : it will redirect your domain name with uppercases to your domain name with lowercases. So, the loop will never end.